# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.estrongs.android.pop.app.FileContentProvider

Tags: android, permissions, android-fileprovider, android-securityexception, fileprovider

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.estrongs.android.pop.app.FileContentProvider from ProcessRecord{341eeb8 5431:xx.xxxx.xxxx/u0a289} (pid=5431, uid=10289) that is not exported from uid 10188
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1686)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1639)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4199)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5548)
       at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2283)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1517)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:516)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:474)
       at org.chromium.base.ContentUriUtils.getDisplayName(ContentUriUtils.java:181)
       at org.chromium.android_webview.AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter$GetDisplayNameTask.doInBackground(AwWebContentsDelegateAdapter.java:2374)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

## Code To open file picker

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open CSV"), READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

## Steps to reproduce issue

1) Open gallery for pick photo

2) From slide menu select [ES File Explore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en_IN)

3) Now some file URI working and some file getting crash

Note :- [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) Already Implement

Answer (score 2):

It seems the issue is in Nougat(7.1.1) nexus(tested!)

**Workaround**

> from your code call ***getFilePathFromUri(this, uri)***

```
public static String getFilePathFromUri(Context context, Uri _uri) {
    String filePath = "";
    if (_uri != null && "content".equals(_uri.getScheme())) {
        //Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        //context.revokeUriPermission(_uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(_uri,
                    new String[]
                            {
                                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,
                                    MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA,
                            }, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            filePath = cursor.getString(0);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            //if file open with third party application
            if (_uri.toString().contains("/storage/emulated/0")) {
                filePath = "/storage/emulated/0" + _uri.toString().split("/storage/emulated/0")[1];
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }

    } else {
        filePath = _uri.getPath();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: please check the exception mentioned in the question. and also check the point no 3 mentioned in above steps(files are not working VIDEOS or DOCS most probably).